# Creating asset with public url in cdk construct for lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

I am trying to create and deploy a `CustomMessageTriggerHandler` lambda for customizing the verification messages sent out by Cognito using cdk, and I would like to include an image asset to be included in the email. This will need to be a public url, but I'm struggling to update its permissions so that the it does not return 403 access denied.

Here is the code I have tried:

```js
export class MyServiceStack extends Stack {
  constructor(app: Construct, id: string, props: MyServiceStackProps) {
    super(app, id, props)

    const imageAsset = new Asset(this, 'logo', {
      path: join(__dirname, './assets/logo.png')
    })

    imageAsset.bucket.grantPublicAccess() // this was my attempt to allow public reads

    const customizeVerificationMessage = new NodejsFunction(
      this,
      'customizeVerificationMessage',
      {
        //...other config
        environment: {
          LOGO_URL: imageAsset.httpUrl
        }
      }
    )

    // ...other code

    const userPool = new UserPool(this, 'userpool', {
      //...other config
      lambdaTriggers: {
        //...other triggers
        customMessage: customizeVerificationMessage
      },
    })

  }
}
```

I expected that this code would create a publicly accessible asset, but

```js
imageAsset.httpUrl
```

included in the email returns 403.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that will not work as Assets will end up in a private S3 Bucket. You should not use the Assets. Instead create an S3 bucket and upload the picture there with the S3Deployment construct.